# filter messages by properties in rabbit queue

Tags: rabbitmq

I have Cent OS with rabbit mq 3.8.2 installed.
From web management tool i see messages in corresponding queue in JSON format like this:

```
{... ,
    "message": {
        "organizationId": 20,
        "title": "----",
        "errorLevel": 1
    },
...
}
```

I need to filter messages by organizationId or some other properties without programming or deleting from queue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can put the "organizationId" at the header, the message can be filtered by [header exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-headers)

Comment: It's not a good idea for exchange to parse the message body, it will slow down the message routing.